# Android TextView linebreak when overrides sibling view

Tags: android

I would like to achive line break of TextView`s text whenever starts to overrides sibling layout.

Here is my view:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="13sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

So basically I have created something like Settings view in Android system.
I want to have title and description on left side and SwitchButton on the right side.
The empty View at the middle is to move SwitchButton at the end of LinearLayout.

How to make TextView`s text is going multiline instead of hiding Switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `RelativeLayout` instead of the root `LinearLayoutCompat`.

Here is my suggestion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/switch_button"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="13sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Descriptionddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
    android:id="@+id/switch_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps~

Answer (score 1):

I hope it help you, this is my suggestion and I have suggest a first relative layout used and manage and layout alignment is used so easily manage all layout so please check it

[image: I hope it help you, this is my suggestion and I have suggest a first relative layout used and manage and layout alignment is used so easily manage all layout so please check it]

Comment: Please edit your answer and include your code as text.